# This MYSQL INSERT code breaks on new server

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, version

I had a small app on Hostgator shared hosting and the below code worked fine and inserted fields. Now I get a a mysql error because the insert returns false. Im thinking maybe the new server which uses MYSQL 5.6.35, has some new insert syntax that  is now making my old syntax incorrect. Can someone who knows and have been following the MYSQL changes please look at the code below and see what is no longer allowed or deprecated.

```
$insertsql = "INSERT INTO members ( lastname, firstname, 
member_dob_month, member_dob_year, spouseslastname,
spousesfirstname, spouse_dob_month, spouse_dob_year, address, city,
state, zip, phone, phone2,  phone3,
memberemail, email2, email3, boatname, boatmake,
propulsion, boatyear, boatlength, slipno, fueltype,
dinghies, ebeacon,  beam, draft, yacht_haven,
registration_no, registration_exp_date, insurance_co, policy_no, 
policy_exp_date, coowned, coowner, talents, volunteer, profiled,
electrical, boatname2, boatmake2, propulsion2,  boatyear2, 
boatlength2, slipno2, fueltype2, beam2, draft2, registration_no2, 
registration_exp_date2, insurance_co2, policy_no2, policy_exp_date2, 
coowned2, coowner2, electrical2, boatname3, boatmake3,
propulsion3, boatyear3,boatlength3,  slipno3, fueltype3, 
beam3, draft3, registration_no3, registration_exp_date3,insurance_co3,
policy_no3, policy_exp_date3, coowned3, coowner3, electrical3, active 
) VALUES ( '$lastname', '$firstname','$member_dob_month', 
'$member_dob_year', 
'$spouseslastname','$spousesfirstname', '$spouse_dob_month', 
'$spouse_dob_year', '$address1', '$city','$state', '$zip', '$phone', 
'$phone2', '$phone3','$email', '$email2', '$email3', '$boatname', 
'$boatmake','$propulsion', '$boatyear', '$boatlength', '$slipno', 
'$fueltype','$dinghies', '$ebeacon', '$beam', '$draft', 
'$yacht_haven','$registration_no', '$registration_exp_date', 
'$insurance_co', '$policy_no', '$policy_exp_date','$coowned', 
'$coowner', '$talents', '$volunteer', 
'$profiled','$electrical', '$boatname2', '$boatmake2', '$propulsion2', 
'$boatyear2','$boatlength2', '$slipno2', '$fueltype2', '$beam2', 
'$draft2','$registration_no2', 
'$registration_exp_date2', '$insurance_co2', '$policy_no2', 
'$policy_exp_date2','$coowned2', '$coowner2', '$electrical2', 
'$boatname3', '$boatmake3','$propulsion3', 
'$boatyear3', '$boatlength3', '$slipno3', '$fueltype3', '$beam3', 
'$draft3', '$registration_no3', 
'$registration_exp_date3','$insurance_co3', '$policy_no3', 
'$policy_exp_date3', '$coowned3', '$coowner3', '$electrical3', 
$active)";


/* Prepare statement */
$stmt = $c1->query($insertsql);
if ($stmt === false) {
trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $insertsql . ' Error: ' . $c1->error, 
E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Here is the SQL error shown on screen:

```
Fatal error: Wrong SQL: INSERT INTO members ( lastname, firstname, 
member_dob_month, member_dob_year, spouseslastname, spousesfirstname, 
spouse_dob_month, spouse_dob_year, address1, city, state, zip, phone, 
phone2, phone3, memberemail, email2, email3, boatname, boatmake, 
propulsion, boatyear, boatlength, slipno, fueltype, dinghies, ebeacon, 
beam, draft, yacht_haven, registration_no, registration_exp_date, 
insurance_co, policy_no, policy_exp_date, coowned, coowner, talents, 
volunteer, profiled, electrical, boatname2, boatmake2, propulsion2, 
boatyear2, boatlength2, slipno2, fueltype2, beam2, draft2, 
registration_no2, registration_exp_date2, insurance_co2, policy_no2, 
policy_exp_date2, coowned2, coowner2, electrical2, boatname3, 
boatmake3, propulsion3, boatyear3,boatlength3, slipno3, fueltype3, 
beam3, draft3, registration_no3, registration_exp_date3,insurance_co3, 
policy_no3, policy_exp_date3, coowned3, coowner3, electrical3, active 
) VALUES ( 'testerr', 'testing','99', '99', '','', '99', '99', '', '', 
in /home/6/public_html/add.php 
on line 129
```

UPDATE: I echoed the SQL and used it in PhpMyadmin to run as SQL to find errors and I found that its identifying all fields without default values as ERRORS. Likely cause new server has STRICT_TRANS_TABLES enabled. Will see if I can get the host to disable for me or I will make each field default value NULL.

Comment: Try checking this :  data type of some of the variable in the VALUES is not matching the type of the column.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: This query's getting pretty involved.  Have you considered using an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent) to simplify your database code?

Comment: There's also some problems here with violating the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Columns like `phone3` are a sign you need a proper relational schema.

Comment: @tadman, thanks, and I get it, but right now im just trying to get it up. App was fine until I moved to new server and now its down and im in get it up mode first. :-) thanks anyway.